# Запрограммировать два отдельных PickerView в одном UIViewController!

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Разбирался я с этой проблемой и научился из одного `PickerView` делать два "столбца" через  `func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int` и `[[],[]]` (кто разбирается, поймет), но хотелось бы уметь программировать именно отдельные `PickerView` в пределах одного класса (любое возможное количество, с возможностью менять другие `PickerView` в зависимости от выбранного Raw первого).

Не могли бы Вы привести пример кода ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview

Comment: оффтопик - вопрос с просьбой дать ссылку на документацию

Comment: Я изменил вопрос. За ссылку спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var picker2: UIPickerView!

    var data1 = ["tra","tra","tra","tra"]
    var data2 = ["la","la","la","la"]       

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        picker1.delegate = self
        picker1.dataSource = self
        picker2.delegate = self
        picker2.dataSource = self        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == picker1 { return data1[row]}
        if pickerView == picker2 {return data2[row]}

        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if pickerView == picker1 {return data1.count}
        if pickerView == picker2 {return data2.count} 

        return 0
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

}
```

Comment: Сам разобрался. Работает.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ так:

```
var picker1 : UIPickerView
var picker2 : UIPickerView

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if (pickerView == picker1) {
        return picker1Data.count
    }
    if (pickerView == picker2) {
        return picker2Data.count
    }
    return 0
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if (pickerView == picker1) {
        return picker1Data[component].count
    }
    if (pickerView == picker2) {
        return picker2Data[component].count
    }
    return 0
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    var l : UILabel!
    if (pickerView == picker1) {
        l.text = picker1Data[component][row]
    }
    if (pickerView == picker2) {
        l.text = picker2Data[component][row]
    }
    return l
}
```

Comment: в функции func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int метод count внутри if не хочет работать....

Comment: Попытался я второй класс создать внутри UIViewController Для описания второго PickerView -> class picker: UIPickerView Delegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, но вылеатет ошибка: Type 'ViewController.picker' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'(((((((((((((((